# sudo asks for password despite not setting one

Tags: sudo, password, debian

Created a user with no password.

```
sudo adduser --disabled-password cowrie
```

I'm currently under this virtual env 'cowrie' but when trying to execute the following command it asks me for the password:

```
sudo apt-get install authbind
```

Even though I just hit enter after 3 attempts, it says the password is wrong. This user 'cowrie' doesn't have any password set.[screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bU9tH.png)

Comment: Please provide OS/product & especially release details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Comment: Unless you are _root_ `sudo` always should ask for a password.

Answer (score 4):

The admin account needs a password to work properly. Go into [Recovery Mode and set a password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006)

Setting up passwordless login properly is easy, and has nothing to do with whether or not the account has a password.

HowTos:

- [Passwordless login on local console](https://askubuntu.com/questions/268466)
- [Passwordless login via SSH (using keys)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930)

Comment: When I re login into my debian machine as root and then switch to user 'cowrie' using 'sudo su - cowrie', it doesn't ask me for a password.

It appears I just needed to run this command 'sudo apt-get install authbind' under root user not under 'cowrie' virtual environment.

Comment: Oh, this is a Debian system. Those are off-topic. Big differences in precisely the areas you are asking about.